# Small capital investment in Germany

Tags: savings, capital-gain, germany

Since from next year I'm planning to take a peek at the brick market in order to buy a house (I'm going to ask a loan - therefore I need a capital to begin with) here in Germany where I live, I'd like to invest every cent I can spare on something that is reliable and sure. 
I would like to invest an amount that can possibly be raised every month (for example: 10.000€ today, +500€ every month).
To be precise, I do have a [bank account with DKB](https://www.dkb.de/privatkunden/dkb_cash/) that allows me to have a more or less good interest on my savings, but I would like to speed up the process a little bit.

Could you guys recommend anything?

Answer (score 2):

If you ant 100% capital protection over such a short time, a time deposit will do that and give you a slightly higher interest than a savings account. Do shop around between banks to find the best rate, and for one that allows you to add the cash you save up. Look here for some details: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termingeld

Comment: With the demand of withdrawal at short notice it is hard to find *Termingeld* with interest that much higher than his already mentionened *DKB Tagesgeld*. Or put differently how much effort (selecting a new bank and registering with them) are you willing to put into something like a mere 0.5% increase of interest?

Answer (score 1):

As you are expecting to need the money in about a year, you are almost certainly unwilling to take pretty much any risk at all. That makes investments such as stocks and bonds totally unsuitable. You may make a better return, but you may also lose 20% of your investment, over such a short time period.

That means a regular savings account which pays interest is your best bet for a reliable and sure investment over such a short time period. You'll want to look around to find which one pays the highest rate of interest.

Comment: What if I wanted to invest in stocks and bonds? Considering that I'm totally newbie, is it worth letting other people manage my money?

Comment: @Noldor130884: if you want to invest in stocks or bonds, you'll have to accept a risk of losing everything (if you put all in one stock and that company goes bankrupt) or at least 20-30% (if you put it into a broad fund but run into a bear market). And letting other people manage your money is really only a viable option if you have a least several hundred thousand Euros, and comes with its own risks.

Comment: Then I guess I have my reply :) 
Could you guys please tell me exactly what you mean by "savings account"? I do (please see link in question) move my money to my card to get 0,9% interest, is it anything different from what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, the terms are different depending on your country. Where I live, a savings account is one which, unlike a chequing account, pays interest. I believe you are looking for an account called Sparbuch, but my German is terrible. Basically, what you want is an account that pays interest, and you want the highest interest rate you can find. It'll likely be 1 - 2%, probably not much higher at the moment.

Comment: Sparkonto is the word.  My German is also terrible, but I had to do some banking in Germany.  If the DKB Girokonto is free and offering 0.9%, you're doing better than most Sparkontos.  DB pays me nothing for a Sparkonto, and charges me Eur5/mo to keep a Girokonto.  I have angemeldet, and I'm out of country, so I don't think I can open anything to replace it.  I would sign up with DKB if I could.

Answer (score -1):

DKB saving interest are running down at 1 october 2016 from now 0,60% to 0,40% (until limit 100.000 €!!). You can get higher interest with Tagesgeld at a different bank, look at one of the comparison portals.
Please notice: DKB high interest is not given at the "DKB Cash account" but only at the "VISA credit card account".

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered to give loans? You can make about 5-8% interest on microloans depending on the risks you want to take.

Also think about short period investing. Consider taking a widely spread fund. Or an ETF. But ensure you have a broker which also gives you an option for a stop loss on funds (very very few banks provide it).